# Authorize.Net Verified Merchant Seal (AuthorizeNetSeal) is not WAI-ARIA compliant

Tags: accessibility, authorize.net, wai-aria, wia

The WAVE plug-in for Chrome give the following alert on the Authorize.Net Verified Merchant Seal:

```
<!-- (c) 2005, 2019. Authorize.Net is a registered trademark of CyberSource Corporation -->
<div class="AuthorizeNetSeal">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id = "my-customer-id";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net:443/anetseal/seal.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Alerts:

Device dependent event handler**

---

I have fixed this alert on other links by adding an id to the `<a>` tag and then adding `onkeydown="myKeyDown(event, 'id of the tag')"` and using the following javascript to click the tag whenever the tag has focus and the <ENTER> or <SPACEBAR> keys are pressed:

```
function myKeyDown(event, controlId) {
    try {
        if ((event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 32) && controlId) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(controlId);
            if (typeof elem.onclick() == "function") {
                elem.onclick.apply(elem);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

**The information from WAVE is:**

Alerts
  Device dependent event handler
What It Means
  An event handler is present that may not be accessible.
Why It Matters
  The JavaScript events in use do not appear to be accessible to both mouse and keyboard users. To be fully accessible, critical JavaScript interaction should be device independent.
How to Fix It
  Ensure that critical functionality and content is accessible by using a device independent event handler (which responds to both keyboard and mouse) or by using both a mouse dependent and a keyboard dependent event handler.
The Algorithm... in English
  One of the following is present:
   - an onmouseover event but not an onfocus event
   - an onclick event on something other than a link, form control, or element with a tabindex value of 0
   - ondblclick

**My Question:  Is there a way to get authorize.net to modify their 'seal.js' javascript to include something approximating the above logic?**
I tried to send an email using the https://developer.authorize.net/support/contact_us.html page but repeatedly received the error "There was a problem submitting your contact information. Please try again."  My contact information was correct, so I thought I'd try here.

Comment: Why not just add the rendered HTML image, link, and text to your own page? Then you'd have complete control of it. The JS isn't doing anything complicated.

Comment: While I could do this myself, modifying their logic (I thought about it before asking the question), I don't want to have to maintain it with future changes, nor does that solve this issue for others who want to be WAI-ARIA compliant.

Comment: If we don't add this div then is there any possibility that payments get failed in live site?

Comment: No- the div is only used to show my company (or whoever uses the div) is a verified merchant on authorize.net.